# simple Merge delete failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
FirstTable

ColumnOne | TabletwoCol | TablethreeColumn |
 1        |  2          |   5              |
 2        |  3          |   6              |
 3        |  8          |   10             |       

SecondeTable (TableTwo)   

TabletwoCol | Coln |
2           | ABC  |
3           | lmn  |
8           |  as  |
 1515       | addd |
```

I want use Merge delete to delete from my  seconde Table by referring `Tabletwocol`
i.e from 
SecondeTable (TableTwo)   following rows should get deleted

```
  2           | ABC  |
    3           | lmn  |
    8           |  as  |
```

should get deleted

I have written

```
 MERGE SecondeTable  PB USING  
             (SELECT DD.TabletwoCol  FROM   FirstTable DD) temptable
                              ON PB.TabletwoCol  =temptable.TabletwoCol 
                                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                                DELETE;
```

I am not getting whats going worng no eerro coming

Comment: can you post a data set from source and destination tables

Comment: added some data and simplified expected output

Comment: Why do you need to use a merge here? This is a simple delete statement and merge just isn't need here.

Comment: @sean it s just for practice

Comment: You really should avoid using MERGE altogether. It is very hard to debug later when you have a problem is in general a poor practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to delete from SecondTable if there is a match in the FirstTable. Try this

```
--DROP TABLE #FirstTable;
--DROP TABLE #SecondTable;
CREATE TABLE #FirstTable
    (
      ColumnOne INT
    , TabletwoCol INT
    , TablethreeColumn INT
    );

INSERT  INTO #FirstTable
        ( ColumnOne
        , TabletwoCol
        , TablethreeColumn
        )
VALUES  ( 1  -- ColumnOne - int
        , 2  -- TabletwoCol - int
        , 5  -- TablethreeColumn - int
        );
CREATE TABLE #SecondTable
    (
      TabletwoCol INT
    , Coln CHAR(5)
    );
INSERT  INTO #SecondTable
        ( TabletwoCol, Coln )
VALUES  ( 2  -- TabletwoCol - int
          , 'ABC'  -- Coln - char(5)
          ),
        ( 3  -- TabletwoCol - int
          , 'def'  -- Coln - char(5)
          );
SELECT  *
FROM    #FirstTable;

SELECT  *
FROM    #SecondTable;

MERGE #SecondTable AS Tgt
USING
    ( SELECT    TabletwoCol
      FROM      #FirstTable
    ) AS Src
ON Src.TabletwoCol = Tgt.TabletwoCol
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    DELETE;

SELECT  *
FROM    #FirstTable;
SELECT  *
FROM    #SecondTable;
```

Comment: Drishya it looks good but for me in my real data it executed and it failed , not deleted any row

Comment: If the code is correct (and the code above with two temp tables should show in general if the code for that would work), then there are three possibilities: You made a mistake in copying the code for your own use, the records do not actually match (one table could have hidden characters) or there is a trigger on the table preventing the deletion.

Comment: I tested the script on the dataset you provided and it worked. Please check if you are missing something from the script I have posted or if you have no match in the tables you are using this logic on.

Comment: @Drishya My silly mistake in my query , this works like charm ..
Thank you....thank you so much ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not working. It looks OK to me.
Maybe you should try using `DELETE`

```
DELETE PB
FROM SecondeTable AS PB
INNER JOIN FirstTable DD
  ON PB.TabletwoCol  = DD.TabletwoCol;
```

Comment: thanks for quick response @vercelli but I specificaly wants to do it with merge

Comment: @PushkarPhule. OK: does `select * from SecondeTable AS PB INNER JOIN FirstTable DD  ON PB.TabletwoCol  = DD.TabletwoCol;` return anything?